# Bindings not working for views first time MvvmLight

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I have been using an approach for MVVM navigation where I create a datatempalte for the viewmodel with the view inside.
The main window is setup like this

```
<Window x:Class="VaultPrez.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:VaultPrez.Views"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:VaultPrez.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="720"
    Width="1280"
    Title="MVVM Light Application"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Skins/MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MainMenuViewModel}">
            <v:MainMenu />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:HeaderViewModel}">
            <v:Header />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:MediaViewModel}">
            <v:MediaViewer />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Header}" />
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding CurrentView}" />
</Grid>
```

The name space v references the actual views and vm is the viewmodels.
This is the Main View Model for this view

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly DataAccessService dataService;

    private ViewModelBase currentView;

    private ViewModelBase header;
...

    public Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase> Views { get; set; }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get { return currentView; }
        set
        {
            if (currentView == null)
                currentView = value;
            else if (currentView != value)
            {
                ViewStates.Push(currentView);
                currentView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
            }
        }
    }

    public ViewModelBase Header
    {
        get { return header; }
        set
        {
            header = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Header");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel(IDataAccessService dataService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService as DataAccessService;
        Views = new Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase>();

        ViewStates = new ObservableStack<ViewModelBase>();

        ViewStates.CollectionChanged += ViewStates_CollectionChanged;
        Views.Add("MainMenu", new MainMenuViewModel(dataService));
        Views.Add("MediaViewer", new MediaViewModel(dataService));
        CurrentView = Views["MainMenu"];
        Header = new HeaderViewModel(dataService);

        registerMessages();
    }

    private void registerMessages()
    {
        MessengerInstance.Register<BackMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            onBack();
        });
        MessengerInstance.Register<ChangeViewMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            CurrentView = Views[message.View];
        });
        MessengerInstance.Register<CancelBackMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            cancelBack = true;
            waiting = false;
        });
        MessengerInstance.Register<SaveMediaMessage>(this, (message) =>
        {
            if (message.Media != null)
                dataService.SaveMedia();
            waiting = false;
        });
    }

    void ViewStates_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((ObservableStack<ViewModelBase>)sender).Count < 1)
            MessengerInstance.Send<SetBackVisibilityMessage>(new SetBackVisibilityMessage() { Visibility = Visibility.Hidden });
        else
            MessengerInstance.Send<SetBackVisibilityMessage>(new SetBackVisibilityMessage() { Visibility = Visibility.Visible });
    }

    private void onBack()
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Back");
        if (currentView == Views["MediaViewer"])
        {
            waiting = true;
            MessengerInstance.Send<AskSaveMediaMessage>(new AskSaveMediaMessage());
            Task t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (waiting)
                    if (!waiting) break;
            });
            t.Wait();
        }
        if(!cancelBack)
        {
            currentView = ViewStates.Pop();
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
        cancelBack = false;
    }
```

but the part that is relevant is that the viewmodels are stored in a dictionary and when the main view receives a message to change the view it moves it to the specified one

```
MessengerInstance.Register<ChangeViewMessage>(this, (message) =>
{
    CurrentView = Views[message.View];
});
```

In theory when the binding CurrentView has a view type of MainMenuViewModel the MainMenu shows etc. which works but on other views when you change to them it doesn't work the first time, all the bindings are empty on the view but when you go back to the main menu try a second time its fine everything is bound properly.

The ViewModel has the data too, nothing is null on the first try.

If it was just a 3 or four view program I'd just iterate through every view during load but I plan on having around 20 views and it could get very time consuming.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

EDIT: here is ViewModelLocator.cs

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataAccessService, DataAccessService>();
        }

        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainMenuViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<HeaderViewModel>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MediaViewModel>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the Main property.
    /// </summary>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
        Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); }
    }

    public MainMenuViewModel Menu
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainMenuViewModel>(); }
    }

    public HeaderViewModel Header
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<HeaderViewModel>(); }
    }

    public MediaViewModel Media 
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MediaViewModel>(); }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up all the resources.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: When you run this and the 'bindings are empty on the view', is your output pane full of binding errors, or does everything look normal?

Comment: Also, could you post the registrations in your ViewModelLocator class (SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyClass>)? This seems vaguely familiar, could be to do with ViewModel instantiation.

Comment: No I believed there are no errors, Ill add the ViewModel Locator above

Comment: Your View is, as far as I can make out, absolutely fine. I use exactly the same mechanism with no issues. I think that the problem may lie in your ViewModel here: 'Views.Add("MainMenu", new MainMenuViewModel(dataService));' . Newing up instances of your ViewModels doesn't work the way you expect it to. Couple of things to try. First thing: Add (true) to the end of your SimpleIoc registrations - SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>(true);. ViewModels are lazy loaded singletons by default. Passing the true parameter into the SimpleIoc registration turns off lazy loading.

Comment: I had an epiphany where I was telling my friend that it seems like there is a second instance with the wrong data and then it occurred to me there was. I create a new instance of the viewmodel rather than using the one in the IOC

Comment: That, unfortunately, won't work. All of your ViewModels are managed by the ViewModelLocator. Newing up an instance of a ViewModel will return the same instance that's in the ViewModelLocator.

Comment: It works, but yours does too on both of my projects. On one really customised view with the thing I thought of it breaks so I will be adding true wanna claim that answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your View is, as far as I can make out, absolutely fine. I use exactly the same mechanism with no issues. I think that the problem may lie in your ViewModel here: 'Views.Add("MainMenu", new MainMenuViewModel(dataService));' . Newing up instances of your ViewModels doesn't work the way you expect it to. Add (true) to the end of your SimpleIoc registrations - SimpleIoc.Default.Register(true);. ViewModels are lazy loaded singletons by default. Passing the true parameter into the SimpleIoc registration turns off lazy loading.